# Is this achievable with a single LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Suppose I have a given object of type `IEnumerable<string>` which is the return value of  method `SomeMethod()`, and which contains no repeated elements. I would like to be able to "zip" the following lines in a single LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<string> someList = SomeMethod();

if (someList.Contains(givenString))
{
    return (someList.Where(givenString));
}
else
{
    return (someList);
}
```

**Edit:** I mistakenly used `Single` instead of `First`. Corrected now.

I know I can "zip" this by using the ternary operator, but that's just not the point. I would just list to be able to achieve this with a single line. Is that possible?

Comment: What is the return type of that method?

Comment: The return type is `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: You are returning both an IEnumerable and a single string.

Comment: What do you expect `someList.Single(givenString)` to mean?

Comment: My apologies. I really meant to use `Where(givenString)` instead of `Single(givenString)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of your desired output requires that you either make two requests for the data, like you are now, or buffer the non-matches to return if no matches are found.  The later would be especially useful in cases where actually getting the data is a relatively expensive call (eg: database query or WCF service).  The buffering method would look like this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> AllIfNone<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                   Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    //argument checking ignored for sample purposes
    var buffer = new List<T>();
    bool foundFirst = false;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            foundFirst = true;
            yield return item;
        }
        else if (!foundFirst)
        {
            buffer.Add(item);
        }
    }

    if (!foundFirst)
    {
        foreach (var item in buffer)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

The laziness of this method is either that of `Where` or `ToList` depending on if the collection contains a match or not.  If it does, you should get execution similar to `Where`.  If not, you will get roughly the execution of calling `ToList` (with the overhead of all the failed filter checks) and iterating the result.

Answer (score 4):

This will return items with given string or all items if given is not present in the list:

```
someList.Where(i => i == givenString || !someList.Contains(givenString))
```

Comment: Doesn't this call .Contains lots of times if there are elements that are not the givenString?

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with the ternary operator?

```
someList.Any(s => s == givenString) ? someList.Where(s => s == givenString) : someList;
```

It would be better to do the Where followed by the Any but I can't think of how to one-line that.

```
var reducedEnumerable = someList.Where(s => s == givenString);

return reducedEnumerable.Any() ? reducedEnumerable : someList;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the return type on the method, which is what you're asking. The first condition returns a string and the second condition returns a collection of strings.

Just return the `IEnumerable<string>` collection, and call `Single` on the return value like this:

```
string test = ReturnCollectionOfStrings().Single(x => x == "test");
```